# How to lock down Windows XP memory?

Tags: windows

What exactly does heart bleed do and how can I protect my Windows XP from heart bleed?  I heard that it takes your personal info by using memory.  Can I lock my memory so that it can't use it?  And if so, some insight on the subject would be nice. :)

Comment: This is not a programming question.  (Or if it is, then it is incredibly naive ... because the solution does not involve programming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you didn't intentionally install openssl on your XP machine and that you aren't using your XP machine as a server. It's likely that the only thing you really need to worry about is websites you communicate with where the possibility that your information could be stolen could result in a significantly negative outcome for you... you need to make sure those companies have patched their servers if they were affected by the issue.